# Understanding LSTM output

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

LSTM state consists of two vectors, one is short-term $h_t$ and the other is long-term $c_t$. Together with the input vector $x_{t+1}$ they form the total input to the following cell on each step. This seems logical and, apparently, works very well in practice.

[image]

What I don't understand is why the cell output is **just** $h_t$. It looks like the next layer might also benefit from having both $(h_t, c_t)$. If for some reason $c_t$ isn't helping at all, the network may learn to ignore it.

Are there LSTM architectures that return both $(h_t, c_t)$ into output?

Comment: On the one hand you say "they form the total input to the following cell on each step", i.e. $h_t$ and $C_t$ are part of the input to cell $t+1$. On the other hand, you say that $C_t$ is not a part of the output of cell $t$. Then how could $C_t$ be an input to cell $t+1$? Would you please clarify your question? By the way, the [excellent post by Christopher Olah](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) (which is the source of your image) says: $C_{t}=f_{t}* C_{t-1}+i_{t}*\tilde{C}_{t}$, i.e. cell $t+1$ uses $C_t$.